# Why do officers sometimes replicate clothes to take into the holodeck?

Tags: star-trek

Sometimes the holodeck itself is used for appropriate costumes and other times characters seem to replicate their costumes outside of the holodeck. Is there any reason for this?

[image]

Comment: @Paulie_D I like the shame of nudity answer you gave. While the clothes are an overlay they would still have mass but I guess you would need to be naked or nearly naked when you enter to do it that way lol. Personally I would just strip down and save a replicator ration tho.

Comment: I'm *never* going into the Holodeck with you

Comment: @JasonBaker lol

Comment: Two words: **Power Failure**.

Comment: Remember, you can always recycle things in the replicator if you want to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Per [**Memory Alpha**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Holodeck#Design)

> The computer may use large magnetic bubbles to simulate surfaces and textures rather than create an object at the molecular level. However, objects created within the holodeck would not exist beyond the holodeck itself, as they only exist as energy. (TNG: "The Big Goodbye") Since holodeck technology can be used with replicator technology, there are some instances where real objects are replicated within the holodeck and are used to interact with the holographic program and/or users; since these objects are real material composed of matter, they can leave the holodeck fully intact.
>
> A holodeck can modify the appearance of persons within it.
>
> The holoprogram depicting the final mission of the NX-class starship Enterprise NX-01 can **project uniforms** suitable to the participants' role **over them**.
>
> A holodeck is able to superimpose an entirely different appearance over a participant. (TNG: "The Offspring")

So, Although the holodeck can simulate other clothes it's only an image overlay (per Memory Alpha). I'd guess that having actual clothes authentic to the set up would enhance the experience.

In addition, a one-time replication of a real costume is *likely* to be more energy efficient than maintaining an image overlay for the entire time a user in in the holodeck especially as the costume can be recyled back into energy again.

---

Finally, pre-replicated clothes can't disappear by accident in a power failure, **and** it saves having to walk to and from the holodeck naked just to get your costume inside.

Not that personal nudity seems to be a *big* issue in Star Trek.

Comment: Yes, I think the feel of authentic (or close to authentic) clothes could be a big issue. Consider Janeway and her Victorian holodeck fantasies - I'd guess that the feel of wearing heavy, poofy skirts and being laced into a corset is part of the experience that can't simply be obtained by using optics to make a Starfleet uniform, or a set of pajamas for that matter, look like an 1860's schoolmistress outfit.

Comment: Nudity does not seem to be a *big* issue in Star Trek - at least not in-universe, think Betazoid marriages or Ferengi females - all participants seem to be fine with it. The only issue seems to be showing it on the show - but then again it is just not Game of Thrones.

Comment: Note that nudity at a Betazoid wedding is a custom...not standard **daily practise.** In fact, in *Nemesis* Picard had to issue orders that everyone would respect Betazoid customs, despite Worf's objections.